# mongodb set/update aggregated unwound fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document from mongo database looking like this:

```
{
  "_id": "00000001",
  "category": "Weather",
  "city": "Salt Lake City",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1663236000000"
    }
  },
  "logs": {
    "2022-09-14 12:00:00": {
      "temp": 55,
      "humidity": 25
    },
    "2022-09-14 14:00:00": {
      "temp": 65,
      "humidity": 35
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to query it and have it look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "00000001",
  "category": "Weather",
  "city": "Salt Lake City",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1663236000000"
    }
  },
  "2022-09-14 12:00:00": "55, 25",
  "2022-09-14 14:00:00": "65, 35"
}
```

Currently my application query looks like:

```
collection.aggregate(
    [{
            $match: {
                _id: {
                    $exists: true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$logs"
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                "series._id": "$_id",
                "series.category": "$category",
                "series.city": "$city",
                "series.date": "$date",
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: "$logs"
            },
        }
    ])
```

which results in:

```
{
  "_id": "00000001",
  "category": "Weather",
  "city": "Salt Lake City",
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1663236000000"
    }
  },
  "2022-09-14 12:00:00": {
      "temp": 55,
      "humidity": 25
    },
  "2022-09-14 14:00:00": {
      "temp": 65,
      "humidity": 35
    }
}
```

My problem is that the logs will add a new field every n hours, so the field names will be dynamic. I need to set/update the values for the unwound fields from objects to a string representation. How can I set/update field values for fields generated through `$unwind` aggregation like the example?

Comment: `logs` is expected to be an array right? The sample document you shared, it has an object value for logs

Comment: My mistake, I am using objects in my database I should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When field names are dynamic, one option is to use `$objectToArray`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: {$exists: true}}},
  {$set: {logs: {$objectToArray: "$logs"}}},
  {$set: {logs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$logs",
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {$concat: [
                {$toString: "$$this.v.temp"},
                ", ",
                {$toString: "$$this.v.humidity"}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {logs: {$arrayToObject: "$logs"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7fAUYnGfrqV)

BTW, `$unwind` is for arrays, not for objects, hence the comment by @CharchitKapoor.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question on how to set the values dynamically, my mistake on confusing the objects and arrays. I still needed to flatten the results, posted another answer with what I ended up using. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [@nimrod serok's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18482310/nimrod-serok) answer, still needed to flatten the logs field in my case. Used `mergeObjects` to flatten the field into the root document, and then used `unset` to remove the original field. This probably isn't the best way to do this but it is working for me. Thanks

```
[{$match: {_id: {$exists: true}}},
        {$set: {logs: {$objectToArray: "$logs"}}},
        {$set: {logs: {
              $map: {
                input: "$logs",
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.k",
                  v: {$concat: [
                      {$toString: "$$this.v.temp"},
                      ", ",
                      {$toString: "$$this.v.humidity"}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", {$arrayToObject: "$logs"}] } } },
        {$unset: "logs"}
      ]
```